# EM algorithm : how to have prior?

Tags: statistics, algorithms, expected-value, maximum-likelihood

I want to use EM algorithm for Gaussian Mixture Model estimation.

I know my data comes from 2 sources A and B.

To perform EM algorithm, I need to input the prior probabilities P(A) and P(B).

My question is : should I use P(A) = P(B) = 0.5 ? Or should I use prior estimation of P(A) and P(B) ?

Answer (score 1):

For EM, you can either initialise each datapoint to one of the clusters using random initializations or K means. From this initialization, we use the sample means as estimates of corresponding Gaussian mean parameter, similarly for the covariance matrix, to start the first iteration. This is a frequentist approach.

Priors are not required for a vanilla EM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The initialization is not an issue as I use this algorithm in a temporal process. So at time t, I can use the 2 sources got at time t-1 as initial gaussians. My question is more about should I use the priors or keep it uniform.

PS: Priors are required in EM (unless all sources are considered equiprobable, or am I missing something. What do you mean by "vanilla EM"?

Comment: Vanilla EM is simple maximum likelihood approach to estimate parameters. Priors are not required in this case. If you doing Bayesian inference, only then you need priors

Comment: thanks for the vocabulary update ;-) After a look at Google, what I am doing is closer to Bayesian inference indeed. I compute P(b | xi) for each sample depending on the prior, and the density functions using Bayes rule. My question is still should I constraint the priors to certain values from the initialization.